# Can't connect to local instance of MongoDB when app is run in a Docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, express

I'm running MongoDB as a standalone server on my local machine. My express app can connect to it fine unless it is run within a container.  In my connection string, I've tried using the IP of my machine, localhost and 127.0.0.1 but neither have worked.  I've also tried binding port 27017 to 0.0.0.0 in the mongo config file but that didn't work either.  Finally, I tried using the --network="host" option in the docker run command but it didn't help.  This is the error I am getting when I run the container:

**MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017**

**DOCKER FILE**

```
FROM node
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/rapidrecipes

COPY server.js /usr/src/rapidrecipes/server.js
COPY deploy-package.json /usr/src/rapidrecipes/package.json

WORKDIR /usr/src/rapidrecipes

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 80

EXPOSE 27017

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

**RUN COMMAND**

docker run -p 80:80 -p 27017:27017 -p 3000:3000 rapidrecipes

**SERVER.JS FILE EXCERPT**

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongo = require('mongoose');
const uuid = require('uuid');

var db = mongo.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/recipedb", function (err, response) {
  if (err) { console.log(err); }
  else { console.log('Connected to ' + db, ' + ', response) }
});
```

Comment: I think you have to add your machine's actual IP instead of 127.0.0.1 in mongo connect URL.

Comment: I mentioned that I have already tried that.

Comment: Try running docker ps to check the container is actually up and running.

Comment: yes it is running

Comment: Well, can you connect to the MongoDB from the inside of container, using `nc`, `telnet`, etc? Inside container, 127.0.0.1 / localhost does not mean your host system. Try using hostname of the Docker host server, where MongoDB is running, just to test, because that is a wrong approach, and you will get it.

Comment: i tried that. It does not work

Answer (score 0):

Docker has built-in "dns" support, meaning containers can find each other by name, so long as they are in the same network!

To create a network:
`docker network create my-network`

Now you need to connect your containers to this network, when running the containers use the `--network [network name]` flag. Like so:

`docker run --network my-network --name recipes-mongo mongo`

`docker run -dp 80:80 -p 3000:3000 --network my-network --name recipes rapidrecipes`

Now change the connection string in your app to `mongo://recipes-mongo/`

I didn't open the ports on the mongo database to the outside here, as it is not needed, but if you would like that, please add the `-p 27017:27017` flag. I also guessed what ports you need for your app, please verify those yourself!

**NOTE:** If you are running the database locally on the host, you should be able to use your host ip, NOT 0.0.0.0, but the one assigned on the local network (such as 192.168.x.x) find this with commands `ifconfig` or `ipconfig`

Comment: My mongoDB instance is not running in a container, it is installed on the same machine that I am running the container on.  Are you saying I still have to run these commands anyway?

Comment: My bad, I edited my answer to what is hopefully the solution of your problem. You should just be able to use your host machine's local network ip!